Removing 0 and NULL columns in a geopackage
I have multiple geopackages with columns containing a mix of 0 and NULL fields. I want to remove these columns where there is no value above 0. I cannot do this manually as each geopackage has 90-100 columns.

Almost an exact duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458672/how-do-i-run-a-qgis-plugin-on-its-python-api and you could easily adapt the script from this answer. You would just need to add an or condition to check for values of zero.

Doing this requires iterating through the layer, checking every value in the field (column) to find the empty fields, and then deleting the empty fields. You can use a pyqgis script like this, run from Python console (this one operates on the currently selected layer):
layer = iface.activeLayer()
fieldsToDelete = []

nulls = 0 # nulls = Zeroes and NULLs
for field in layer.fields(): # repeat for every field
    for feature in layer.getFeatures(): # check every feature
        # if value is 0 or NULL, counts towards "nulls"
        if (feature.attribute(field.name())== NULL) or (feature.attribute(field.name())== 0):
            nulls += 1
    if nulls == layer.featureCount(): # if ALL features are 0/null, drop the field
        fieldsToDelete.append(field.name())
    # reset for the next field
    nulls = 0

# apply changes (never delete fields while iterating over the layer)
layer.startEditing()
for empty_field in fieldsToDelete:
    layer.deleteAttribute(layer.fields().indexFromName(empty_field))
    print(f'Field {empty_field} deleted')
layer.commitChanges()

There is probably a better/faster way, but this works for me...
